# How to retrieve item 'n' from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a "Master List" by retrieving the first item from lists A, B, and C, and appending list D with those values, then iterating on that.

I'm using the code:

```
i = 1
while i < 4:
    listA.append(str(i))
    listB.append(str(i + 10))
    listC.append(str(i + 100))
    i += 1
print(listA, listB, listC)
```

Which returns: `[1, 2, 3] [11, 12, 13] [101, 102, 103]`

What I *want* to end up with would look like: `[1, 11, 101, 2, 12, 102, 3, 13, 103]`

I tried using the following code:

```
while k < 4:
    listD.append([item[k] for item in listA])
    listD.append([item[k] for item in listB])
    listD.append([item[k] for item in listC])
    k += 1

print(listD)
```

But this returns the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: You should definitely be using a `for` loop if you know how many iterations it will have

Comment: there's no need for a list comprehension, you're already iterating over the list. You can just do `listD.append(listA[k])`.

Comment: The reason you're getting that `TypeError` is because `[item[k] for item in listA]` is iterating over the list, so the variable `item` is set to `1` and you try to access `item[k]` since is the number 1 and not a list, you can't ask for the n-th element of an integer because that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: You coudl take your lists and transform them by doing `[x for z in zip(list1, list2, list3) for x in z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pythonic code:

```
>>> 
>>> 
>>> A=[1,2,3]
>>> B=[11,12,13]
>>> C=[101,102,103]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> D=[]
>>> 
>>> [D.extend(a) for a in zip(A,B,C)]
[None, None, None]
>>> 
>>> D
[1, 11, 101, 2, 12, 102, 3, 13, 103]
>>>
```

So your python code should like this:

```
D = []
for i in range(1,4):
    listA.append(str(i))
    listB.append(str(i + 10))
    listC.append(str(i + 100))
[D.extend(a) for a in zip(A,B,C)]
print(D)
```

This is just a starting point , you can write it better.

Comment: welcome , I could do it in one line , but one lining hurts readibility , and python code must be super readable , the zen of python

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
listA, listB, listC = [], [], []

i = 1
while i < 4:
    listA.append(str(i))
    listB.append(str(i + 10))
    listC.append(str(i + 100))
    i += 1

print(listA, listB, listC)

listD = [item for sublist in zip(listA, listB, listC) for item in sublist]
print(listD)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3'] ['11', '12', '13'] ['101', '102', '103']
['1', '11', '101', '2', '12', '102', '3', '13', '103']
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping component lists altogether?

```
#! /bin/env python3
orders_of_magnitude = 3
numbers = 4

out = [10**om - 0**om + n for n in range(1,numbers) for om in range(orders_of_magnitude)]
print(out)
```